# Drawing rectangles

Tags: arduino, processing

For a new course I'm attending I have to create a connection between Processing and Arduino. I want that if a certain switch is ON that a rectangle is drawn in Processing.

For this I have 3 switches and one button. The three switches represent a color: Red, Green, and Blue. So the user should first pick a color and then press te button to let a rectangle be drawn in that certain color.

After that, the user should be able to turn of the switch for that color, turn on the switch of another color and draw a second rectangle by pressing the switch. This is unfortunately not working for me.

Once one rectangle is drawn, it's not possible to draw another rectangle. I'm quite new to this so I'm sorry if my code is very bad!

My Arduino code:

```cpp
int switchPinRed = 21;
int switchPinGreen = 22;
int switchPinBlue = 23;
int buttonPinRect = 20;

void setup() {
  pinMode(switchPinRed, INPUT);             // Set pin 0 as an input
  pinMode(switchPinGreen, INPUT);
  pinMode(switchPinBlue, INPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPinRect, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);                    // Start serial communication at 9600 bps
}

void loop() {

  if (digitalRead(buttonPinRect) == HIGH) {
    Serial.print(1);
  }

  else if (digitalRead(switchPinRed) == HIGH) {
    Serial.print(2);
  }

  else if (digitalRead(switchPinGreen) == HIGH) {
    Serial.print(3);
  }

  else if (digitalRead(switchPinBlue) == HIGH) {
    Serial.print(4);
  }
}
```

And my Processing code:

```java
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;  
int val; 

int[] rects = new int [3];

void setup() 
{
  size(600, 200);
  String portName = Serial.list()[0];
  myPort = new Serial(this, "/dev/tty.usbmodem3330431", 9600);

  for (int i=0; i < 3; i++) {
    rects[i] = 0;
  }
}

void draw()
{
  if ( myPort.available() > 0) {  
    val = myPort.read();
  }


  background(255); 

  for (int i =0; i < 3; i++) {

  if (val == 1) {
      if (val == 2) {
        fill(255, 0, 0);


      } else if (val == 3) {
        fill(0, 255, 0);


      } else if (val == 4) {
        fill(0, 0, 255);


      }

      rect(random(50), random(50), 100, 100);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `val` can't be simultaneously `1` and any other value.

Comment: Oh okay thanks! And in what way can I change the other val's to something else in a way that it does work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code doesn't make sense:

```
if (val == 1) {
  if (val == 2) {
    fill(255, 0, 0);
  } else if (val == 3) {
    fill(0, 255, 0);
  } else if (val == 4) {
    fill(0, 0, 255);
  }
  rect(random(50), random(50), 100, 100);
}
```

First you check whether `val == 1`, and if so you check if `val == 2`. That will never be the case. Perhaps you meant something like this?

```
if (val == 1) {
  //fill?
}
else if (val == 2) {
  fill(255, 0, 0);
} else if (val == 3) {
  fill(0, 255, 0);
} else if (val == 4) {
  fill(0, 0, 255);
}
rect(random(50), random(50), 100, 100);
```

Comment: I want to say that if the switchPinRect is HIGH and switchPinRed is HIGH that a red rectangle is drawn. And the same for the other colors. I thought I could do that by first checking if the val is 1 and if the val is also 2 that this would happen. I now understand that val can't be 1 and 2, but I don't know how to code this in another way :(

Comment: @JessieenEmma Instead of using a single `int` value to represent the state of your sketch, you might want to use a set of `boolean` values instead. (I'm thinking `drawRectangle`, `isRed`, `isGreen`, and `isBlue`.) Set those booleans based on which value comes from your Arduino, and draw your rectangle (or not) based on those booleans.

Comment: Okay, I think that I get that. But how do I know that the int drawRectangle reads only the output of the pin the button for the drawing of the rectangle is connected to?

Comment: @JessieenEmma In my suggestions, `drawRectangle` would not be an `int`. It would be a `boolean`.